# Kotlin throws false errors for everything in VS Code

Tags: java, android, bash, kotlin, visual-studio-code

This **it's complicated to explain, so patience**, please.

I **started learning Kotlin a few weeks ago, but left it** because other things **and continue today**, but **every line of code it's highligthed with errors** without reason.

Even a simple code as a "Hello World" got errors for everything.

Code:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val variable:String = "Hello world"
    print(variable)
}
```

Problems message in vscode:

```bash
Cannot access built-in declaration 'kotlin.String'. Ensure that you have a dependency on the Kotlin standard library
Unresolved reference: print
Cannot access built-in declaration 'kotlin.String'. Ensure that you have a dependency on the Kotlin standard library
```

JSON log error by vscode:

```
[{
    "resource": "/home/my_username/programming/courses/kotlin/first.kt",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#1",
    "code": "MISSING_BUILT_IN_DECLARATION",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Cannot access built-in declaration 'kotlin.String'. Ensure that you have a dependency on the Kotlin standard library",
    "source": "kotlin",
    "startLineNumber": 2,
    "startColumn": 19,
    "endLineNumber": 2,
    "endColumn": 25
}]
```

```
[{
    "resource": "/home/my_username/programming/courses/kotlin/first.kt",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#1",
    "code": "UNRESOLVED_REFERENCE",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Unresolved reference: print",
    "source": "kotlin",
    "startLineNumber": 3,
    "startColumn": 5,
    "endLineNumber": 3,
    "endColumn": 10
}]
```

```
[{
    "resource": "/home/my_username/programming/courses/kotlin/first.kt",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#1",
    "code": "MISSING_BUILT_IN_DECLARATION",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Cannot access built-in declaration 'kotlin.String'. Ensure that you have a dependency on the Kotlin standard library",
    "source": "kotlin",
    "startLineNumber": 3,
    "startColumn": 11,
    "endLineNumber": 3,
    "endColumn": 19
}]
```

**But this compile and work, without problems in the terminal**:

```bash
cd "/home/my_username/programming/courses/kotlin/" && kotlinc first.kt -include-runtime -d first.jar && java -jar first.jar
```

Output:

```bash
Hello world
```

Use Ubuntu 22.04 and installed kotlin via snap (as indicated in the [official website](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/command-line.html)):

```bash
sudo snap install --classic kotlin
```

In vscode use the follow extensions that could be implicated in the problem:

- [fwcd.kotlin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fwcd.kotlin)
- [mathiasfrohlich.Kotlin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mathiasfrohlich.Kotlin)
- [usernamehw.errorlens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=usernamehw.errorlens)

I can run the cli compiler and every tool, but vscode/vscode-extensions error messages broke for no apparent reason, and just with this language.

**IMPORTANT: The problem isn't the installation of the language itself, since the code compile and run witout problems, and don't throw error in terminal when executed.**

Comment: Have you tried this?
https://medium.com/@agavatar/programming-with-kotlin-in-visual-studio-code-1d745d6b4ad1

Comment: the alternative is to drop vscode and use intellij

Comment: @Desmond Yes, actually, i follow that tutorial to set kotlin in my machine and vscode

Comment: @al3c that it's exactly what i don't want to do, i try it and didn't like it :v

Comment: How about this?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A7nnx267pkw

Comment: @Desmond as i said, no. The code run, the code compile, everything it's fine in the system until vscode try to detect errors in the script, that it's the problem, detect false errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Used vscode Bisect tool and dentified the problem. It's this extension:

- Nombre: Kotlin
- ID: fwcd.kotlin
- Descripción: Smart code completion, debugging, linting, syntax highlighting and more for Kotlin
- Versión: 0.2.26
- Editor: fwcd
- Vínculo de VS Marketplace: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fwcd.kotlin

This extension throw all the errors, disable and everything it's fine.

Alredy reported in this [Github Issue](https://github.com/fwcd/vscode-kotlin/issues/101)

Until date (*09/08/2022*), the issue it's open and bug it's there.

Answer (score 0):

I was using **kotlin** some time ago and everything worked fine (vscode version was `1.69.2` at the time). I tried again today after seeing your question and got an error. (At this time, the vscode version has been upgraded to `1.70`)

After I rolled back the vscode version to `1.69.2` it still didn't solve the problem.

So I upgraded the version to `1.70` again and the kotlin code is running normally again.

So, please uninstall your [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) and install it again. ( *The current latest version is [`1.70`](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_70)*. )

If it doesn't work once, reinstall it again.

This may be a bug, I will raise an issue on GitHub.

Comment: didn't work. Try it 3 times, with reboots between each installation, and didn't work. There are high chances that it's a bug, because i updated vscode in that lapse of time. If raised the issue, please share the link here to divulge the problem.

Comment: Sorry for the late link. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/157484